# How to add value to dictionary without replacing it?

Tags: swift, dictionary, swift3

I'm trying to append values inside dictionary without replacing it for example:

```
var dict = [String:Any]()
dict["login"] = ["user" : "jon"]
//...
//...
//...
dict["login"] = ["password": "1234"]
```

When I'm trying to add a value to login at the second time , it's overwrite the first value.
How can I append this data?
I'm using Swift 3.

- Edit: let me rephrase my question a little bit. 
  I want to build a dynamic dictionary which I'll post it to alamoFire as body parameters. so if I have an JSON that looks like this:

  ```
  {
  "name" : "Jon",
   "details" : {
                  "occupation" : "lifeguard"
                  "years_of_ex" : 3
   }
   "more_details" : "extra info"
   "inner_body" : {
                  "someInfo" : "extra info"
   }
   ... // there might be lots of other fields since it's dynamic
   ... // the server expect to have missing fields and not empty ones
  }
  ```

I want to add dynamically details since I don't know how my Dictionary would looks like. 
so adding to values to dictionary without override them is a must for me.

Comment: `dict["login"]?["password"] = "1234"` but more to the point... Is there a reason you're using a dictionary for this, rather than a struct or a class?

Comment: Yup, I need dictionary for Alamofire body parameters.. I have edited my question so it will be more clear

Comment: Just a suggestion, you can have a look at [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON) which makes it very simple to work with JSON data in Swift. It makes the code much more readable and optional wrapping is done automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Define an intermediate variable and assign to it:

```
var dict = [String:Any]()
dict["login"] = ["user" : "jon"]

if var login = dict["login"] as? [String: String] {
    login["password"] = "1234"
    dict["login"] = login
}
```

Comment: You will very quickly lose tracks over which item is in your dictionary and which one is not. Already you can see manipulating the dictionary is a small hassle. I highly recommend that you define a `struct` to contain all possible data. For Swift 3, you can use `ObjectMapper` to convert it to JSON. For Swift 4, there's `Codable` that you can look into.

Comment: I saw ObjectMapper on GitHub, but Is it possible to convert it to dictionary ? and what if I need some of the data? how can I avoid nil fields ?

Answer (score 0):

To reflect for the edit in the question: without knowing the exact structure of the dictionary, you cannot modify it as you wish. Anyways, modifying a JSON dictionary directly is really bad practice.

Parse the JSON response into a custom object, modify the object as you wish, then encode the object back to JSON and use it as your request's body.

If you don't want to write the JSON parsing function yourself, have a look at [ObjectMapper](https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper). It can both map a JSON response to objects and can also map an object to JSON.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot directly "append" new values to a dinamic dictionary without knowing the type and content.

Since

```
dict["login"]
```

returns you a `Any?` you have no way to directly manipulate it.

Do you have any ideas of the possible combinations of the content of each dictionary leaf?

you could write a recursive methods that tries to downcast the content of the leaf and base on it, try to do something

```
switch dict["login"] {
    case is [String: Any?]:
         // check that the key does not already exist, to not replace it
    case is [Int: Any?]:
         // Do something else

}
```